# Why do we need to worry about the batch dimension when specifying a model in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

It seems a bit cumbersome to take into account the batch dimension for every layer in a neural network. Why don't we have some functionality in Tensorflow that can just set the batch size for an entire model?

Answer (score 3):

In tensorflow you **do not** have to take into account the batch size.

In the [MNIST Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html) it's explained how tensorflow handles batches of every size.

Quoting the tutorial:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
```

The input images x will consist of a 2d tensor of floating point numbers. Here we assign it a shape of `[None, 784]`, where 784 is the dimensionality of a single flattened MNIST image, *and `None` indicates that the first dimension, corresponding to the batch size, can be of any size.*

Comment: I understand this part. I understand that the batch size doesn't need to be set in advance. However, variables for every layer still carry the batch size dimension, and you always need to worry about this dimension when writing everything in your model, especially for reshapes. I'm talking about a scenario where variables don't carry this dimension at all, but at the very end, you say, replicate the same graph for every sample in the batch. This can save a lot of complexity.

Comment: Tensorflow is a generic computation framework. Some ops perform batchwise operations, some don't have a concept of batch size. Examples of the latter include matmul and all the various elementwise operations like tanh and tensor addition. These just follow numpy-like broadcasting rules. Requiring every op to handle batches would actually restrict the tensorflow api and make developing new operations more complicated.

Comment: @HanhanLi No you don't need to worry about batch size. What tensorflow does  for the linear part is simply XW + b and X can have any number of rows (batch size). Tensorflow don't need know that number. It just calculate the matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

I think what Hanhin Li what to say is regarding custom layers where you need to do some reshaping like this one:

Suppose that the input shape to the model is (batch_size, frames) and you want to implement a preprocessing layer that removes some frames based on a condition . The layer to do this could be something like this:

```
def process_file(data): 
    new_frames = tf.TensorArray(data.dtype, size=0, dynamic_size=True) 
    i = 0
    for frame in data:
       if tf.math.count_nonzero(frame) == 0:
           new_frames.write(i, frame)
           i += 1 
    return new_frames.stack()


class Preprocessing(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Preprocessing, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, training=True, **kwargs):
        return process_file(inputs)
```

The problem is that once you fit the model with batches the `process_file()` from `Preprocessing()` will received the batch size so all the function is messed up as now `for frame in data` will iterate over the batches instead of frames (because of the batch dimension added).

So I think the question is, can you add something to the layer subclass to not send the batch dimension to the preprocessing function and stack the batches afterwards?

I'm sorry I dont have the answer to that. I' m struggling with the same issue -.-